# getting child category's parent name with a single query in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table named "category". the basic structure looks like this-

```
------     --------     ------
cat_id     cat_name     parent
------     --------     ------
1          test1        NULL
2          test2        NULL
3          test3        2
4          test4        1
5          test5        3
```

now i want all the category data with parent category **name** (not only id) in a single query. is that possible? i could do it by using a second query (getting child's parent name) in a while loop and merging data as a whole. but is it possible to do this with a single query?

Comment: Your question is ambiguous: do you want to select all category data and the parent category name, or do you want to select all category data which has a given (searched) parent category name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Join the table with itself**, using the `parent` column to link to the cat_id of the parent.

```
SELECT c1.cat_id as childID, c1.cat_name ChildName, c2.cat_name as ParentName
from category c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN category c2
ON c1.parent = c2.cat_id
```

- Be careful: since some elements have no parents (`NULL`), I put a `LEFT
  OUTER JOIN` so those rows are displayed as well. If you don't want
  that, use a `JOIN` instead of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.
- You can also show the lines, but display something else (empty or a
  text or ...) instead of the `NULL` by using `COALESCE`.
- You can consider the result as one (big) new table, so you can add WHERE clauses as you usually do, for example filtering on the parent name: `WHERE c2.cat_name = 'test2'`

Answer (score 0):

```
Select p.cat_id, p.cat_name, c.cat_id, c.cat_name, c.parent 
From category Left Join category On p.cat_id = c.parent 
Where p.cat_name = 'name'
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT c1.`category_name` AS category, c2. `category_name` AS sub_category
FROM (

SELECT * 
FROM  `category`
) AS c1
INNER JOIN (

SELECT * 
FROM  `category`
) AS c2 ON c1.`category_id` = c2.`category_id`