# Getting Parent name from same table

Tags: laravel, parent-child

I have a table Which is as below:

**quotes_glass_types**

```
 id | name                    | parent_id
 1  | Annealed glass           |  Null
 2  |  Clear Float Glasss     |   1
 3  |  Tinted glass           |   1
 4  |  Toughened glass        |   Null
 5  |  Clear toughened Glass  |   4
```

Here, name having Null parent_id are the parent.
How do i display glass name  along with their parent in laravel? for example;

```
{
  id:2,
  name:Clear Float glass,
  category:Annealed glass
 }
```

what do i do after this?:

```
$glass=\DB::table('quotes_glass_types')->select('id','name','parent_id as category')->get();
```

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10427241/getting-child-categorys-parent-name-with-a-single-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get Name with Parent Name than you can use below query :

```
SELECT qgt.name,pqgt.name FROM quotes_glass_types as qgt LEFT JOIN quotes_glass_types as pqgt ON qgt.id = pqgt.parent_id
```

You have to use LEFT JOIN on the same table. I don't know how to write this query in Laravel but this query works in phpmyadmin.

Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this-

```
DB::table('quotes_glass_types')

->select('quotes_glass_types.*', 'qgt.name as parent_name')

->leftjoin('quotes_glass_types as qgt', 'qgt.id', '=', 'quotes_glass_types.parent_id')

->get();
```